# Excel, generating hyperlinks from CSV cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet populated with references to file names (mostly photos). I want to create links in a different sheet that will be clickable and will open up the file. I know how to use =HYPERLINK() however quite a lot of the cells have multiple file references separated by a comma within the single cell. From research it has become obvious that there is no way to map multiple hyperlinks to a single cell. However is there a simple way to map the references to individual cells moving across to the column to the right? I have extensively searched online however can't find any other similar cases. Simple example cases below.

Input cell E.g: "ae345_asd,c3stryui"

Wanted output : "C:/files/Photos/ae345_asd.jpg""C:/files/Photos/c3stryui.jpg"

I also have no control into how many references could be in a single cell and currently there are cells with around 5+ references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started.  Highlight the cells with addresses and run the macro.  It will loop through each cell highlighted, split the contents by the comma delimiter and create hyperlinks for each one in the cells to the right of the highlighted cell.  This method uses nested loops and would be slow if your processing a large amount of data but I'm guessing that's not the case here so I kept it simple.

```
Sub splitHyperLinks()
    Dim sel As Range
    Set sel = Selection

    Dim arr() As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    'Loop through each cell highlighted
    For Each cell In sel
        arr = Split(cell, ",")

        'Loop through each link in cell
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
            'Create hyperlink
            cell.Offset(0, i + 1).Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell.Offset(0, i + 1), Address:="C:/files/Photos/" & arr(i) & ".jpg", SubAddress:="", TextToDisplay:="Link"
        Next i
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

Result

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, how would I get this to display on a different sheet and starting column?